# Is it possible to find out what user uploaded a kubernetes secret?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Is it possible to find out what user uploaded a particular Kubernetes secret? I can describe the secret to see what files exist in it, and I see the age with get secrets, but I don't know who put it there.

We just want to know who to ask if it's safe to delete a particular secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you have [auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) enabled.